# Kinect 2 on Mac, The kinect is connected to Hi-Speed USB not SuperSpeed

Tags: macos, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm trying to use Kinect2 for a project. But it has a problem that the device is recognised on Hi-Speed Bus not on the SuperSpeed Bus. I suspect that due to this problem, the kinect programm is not able to be opened. The laptop is a Early 2015 Macbook Pro, OS X: Yosemite.

Has anyone come across similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

The [libfreenect2 FAQ](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2#protonect-complains-about-no-device-connected-or-failure-opening-device) says if that happens, you should:

> try unplugging the Kinect from power source with the USB cable connected, and plug the power again, then verify.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a combination of Macbook Pro and Yosemite. 
The problem was fixed simply by upgrading to El Capitan. The same issue happened on 2 different Macbook pro with Yosemite. 
But it worked perfectly on a IMac with Yosemite.

Comment: Good that you figured it out. To show your problem is solved, you should accept your own answer (click the checkmark to the left of the answer)